# Make going into extra directory

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Im trying to make a simple hello module.

This is the c file:

```
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Daniel");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Simple Hello World module");

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;    // Non-zero return means that the module couldn't be loaded.
}

static void __exit hello_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_cleanup);
```

This is the makefile:

```
obj-m := hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Ive placed them in ~/HelloModule
and when I run the make command there it gives me this error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-25-generic/build M=/home/dan/HelloModule modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-25-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/dan/HelloModule/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/dan/HelloModule/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/dan/HelloModule' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/dan/HelloModule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-25-generic'
makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

For some reason on the 4th line it seems like the make script is trying to go into the directory /home/dan/HelloModule/Makefile, which isn't a directory. any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. its not trying to access a directory its trying to access the Makefile which is case sensitive so it has to be Makefile not makefile

Comment: Tip: all standard Linux filesystems are case-sensitive.  You should get into the habit of considering the characters "a" and "A" to be just as unique as the characters "x" and "8", if using Linux-based distributions: seeing the wrong case needs to raise alarms just as large as the wrong character.  This is also true of most other UNIX-based systems such as the BSD's, Solaris, etc.  MacOS is the exception here.